# Is there any way to enable/disable log queries in Grafana based on a multi-variable?

Tags: grafana, logql

I have a Grafana dashboard with a Logs panel. The panel has 3 separate queries: A, B & C. Each query filters the log data in a different way and displays the results in a different way. Having all 3 queries in the same panel rather than in separate panels is helpful because the results get displayed chronologically in relation to each other. By default I have A & B enabled, with C disabled.

I would like to be able to toggle each one on/off by selecting options from a variable drop-down instead of having to "Edit" or "Explore" the log panel, but can't quite work out how to do that.

So far, I have created a custom multi-select variable called `LogTypes` which can have any combination of the values `Verbose`, `Messages` & `Errors`. I initially (naively) tried changing the start of query A from:

```
{app="$app"}
```

to:

```
{app="$app", "Messages"=~"$LogTypes"}
```

to essentially try to only "enable" query "A" when `Messages` was selected as a Log Type, but it seems that LogQL expects "Messages" to be an identifier rather than a string. Is there another way to compare a *constant* string to a variable string in order to turn the query on/off like this?
Alternatively, is there some other functionality that I should potentially be looking at to achieve the same result?